# Enigmatic maths

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

$\left\lceil{\left(\left(2-1\right)^{19}+5\right)^{\left(\frac{20-23-5+14}{\left(\cos\left(\cos\left(\sin\left(\sqrt{\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{20-\sqrt{25}\cdot19}{9-24}\right)\right)}\right)\right)\right)\right)}\right)}}\right \rceil$

What word is conveyed by this math expression?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It conveys the word

> Lucky

Because

> Take all the integers in the expression (in order): `2, 1, 19, 5, 20, 23, 5, 14, 20, 25, 19, 9, 24`
>  Convert with A1Z26: `basetwentysix`
>  Evaluate the math expression; the result is `5379892`
>  Convert that number to base26 (letters only version), and you get `LUCKY`